# When starting a Skype conversation, what do people usually say at the very beginning?

Tags: conversation

So, I've contacted to my companion through Skype. What do people usually say first in this situation? "**How are you**"? or giving a name first and then "**How are you**"? Or are those two phrases are incompatible with each other... if you give a name do you need to avoid **How are you**?

Comment: What do you mean by "companion"... because one usually knows the name of their "companion".

Comment: Curious, is the Skype interaction in your native language that formalized? Every Skype I've been on has been pretty informal. As with your previous question, we really need to know the level of formality you feel is necessary... are you talking to a client, a co-worker, a friend, your boss? Give us more information for the situation.

Comment: @Catija Ok, how can I call a man who I'm going to talk to?

Comment: @Catija I'm going to talk more likely to a boss than a co-worker....

Comment: It's not so different from a phone conversation where you know from caller ID who is calling. How would you greet this person on the phone?

Comment: @ColleenV If I called up the person, I'd give them a name first...

Comment: My conversations on Skype usually start with a heartfelt prayer to the VOIP gods for a streaming rate greater than 56.6K...

Comment: 1) Are you referring to skype's audio/VOIP function or to its chat/IM function? 2) Your use of *companion* seems odd. Did you mean *colleague* or *company*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with  "Hello, this is Colleen." Then you should pause for just a moment to see if they want to respond,  and if not, ask any polite question like "How are you?", "Is this a good time to talk?", or "Is my volume OK?"

Personally, I find that questions about the quality of our connection and whether they can easily hear me when I speak are the most useful sorts of questions.  You want to correct any issues with the volume or position of your microphone and/or webcam before you really start talking.

Answer (score 2):

I most often start Skype conversations with "Hello!", or "Hi, !" Similarly to a phone conversation, the other person will usually reply with a similar greeting, possibly followed by "How are you?"

I find that Skype and other VOIP calls tend to follow similar protocols as an old-fashioned phone call.