# How to say hello via Skype?

Tags: greetings

Sometimes I need to ask for helps from other colleagues that I never know before, so I usually say hello and introduce myself, and then can I say "Nice to meet you on Skype"?

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When starting a Skype conversation, what do people usually say at the very beginning?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60763/when-starting-a-skype-conversation-what-do-people-usually-say-at-the-very-begin)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very formal when you say it that way. When you're already using skype, it would be implied that you are meeting them in Skype, so that is unnecessary information.

For example, if I'm traveling in a car and picking someone up for the first time, I wouldn't say "Nice to meet you in a car", because we are both already in the car.

I would probably say a plain "hello" or "Hi, nice to meet you", that is, unless you have met them before in person. Then you can specify where you are currently meeting them and it comes off as a joke

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the means of communication shouldn't lend itself to the greeting - for example, one wouldn't say:

> nice to meet you on the telephone.

...if they were calling a person for the first time.

Normal common courtesy should more than suffice - a 'hello' or 'nice to meet you' should be more than enough, as you would in a real life encounter.

Somewhat ironically, it has become more acceptable to say:

> Nice to meet you in real life.

...if you are having a face to face meeting, where all previous correspondence has been by phone/email/skype.